# Connect and query Mongo database over SSH with private key in Python

Tags: python, mongodb, ssh, pymongo, paramiko

i have a code file `mongo.py` like below to connect n query mongo with `username` `host` `password` and its work, but how i can connect to ssh with ssh `address` `username` and auth method `private_key` ? `private_key` in the other file

here is my sample `config` with ssh:

```
sql_local = {'mongomdm':{'host':'xx.xxx.xxx.xx', 'user':'aaa', 'pkey':'/Users/satu/dua/tiga/config/settings/googlecloud_dev_rsa'}}
```

i have ready some references and should import library like this ?

```
from paramiko import SSHClient, AutoAddPolicy, RSAKey
from paramiko.auth_handler import AuthenticationException
from scp import SCPClient, SCPException
from io import StringIO
```

here is my code file `mongo.py`

```
import csv                                                                              
import pandas as pd
from pymongo import MongoClient
from pymongo.errors import ConnectionFailure
import config.config as cfg
import config.modules.common as comm
from bson.objectid import ObjectId

class mongoFunc:
def __init__(self):
    self.types = 'mongodb'
    self.host = cfg.sql_local[self.types]['host']
    self.user = cfg.sql_local[self.types]['user']
    self.password = cfg.sql_local[self.types]['password']
    self.uri = 'mongodb://{user}:{password}@{host}'.format(user = self.user, password = self.password, host = self.host)

def connection(self):
    try:
        client= MongoClient(self.uri)
        client.server_info()
        print('Connection Established')
    except ConnectionFailure as err:
        raise(err)
    return client

def get_collection(self, client, database, collection):
    self.client= client
    self.database= database
    self.collection= collection

    db= self.client[self.database]
    return db[self.collection]

def get_query(self,id_data= None,start_date=None,end_date=None,query=None):
    self.id = ObjectId(id_data)
    self.start_date = start_date
    self.end_date = end_date
    self.query = query
    
    if self.end_date:
        script= {'date':{'$gt':self.start_date,'$lte':self.end_date}}
    if self.end_date is None:
        script= {'date':{'$gt':self.start_date}}
    if self.id:
        script = {'_id':{'$gt':self.id}}
    if self.query:
        script.update(self.query)
    return script

def get_data_to_pandas(self, database, collection, query, skip, limit=None):
    self.database = database
    self.collection = collection
    self.query = query
    self.limit = limit
    self.skip = skip

    self.client = self.connection()
    self.collection = self.get_collection(self.client,self.database,self.collection)

    if limit:   
        cursor = self.collection.find(self.query).skip(self.skip).limit(self.limit)
    if not limit :
        cursor = collection.find(self.query).skip(self.skip)
    df = pd.DataFrame(list(cursor))
    return df
```

Edit:

```
def connection(self):
    try:
        print('Establishing SSH Connection')
        self.client = paramiko.SSHClient()
        self.client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        if (self.password == ''):
            private_key = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file(self.pkey)
            self.client.connect(hostname=self.host, port=self.port, username=self.user, pkey=private_key, allow_agent=False,look_for_keys=False)
            print("Connected to the server"),self.host
        else:
            self.client.connect(hostname=self.host, port=self.port, username=self.user, password=self.password, allow_agent=False,look_for_keys=False)    
            print("Connected to the server"),self.host
    except paramiko.AuthenticationException:
        print("Authentication failed, please verify your credentials")
        result_flag = False
    except paramiko.SSHException as sshException:
        print("Could not establish SSH connection: %s") % sshException
        result_flag = False
    else:
        result_flag = True
    return result_flag

def get_collection(self, client, database, collection):
    self.client= client
    self.database= database
    self.collection= collection

    db= self.client[self.database]
    return db[self.collection]`
```

I got an error:

```
line 64, in get_collection
    db= self.client[self.database]
TypeError: 'bool' object is not subscriptable
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

Unless MongoClient module supports SSH tunneling on its own (I do not know), you have to implement port forwarding explicitly.

The easiest solution is with [`sshtunnel` module](https://pypi.org/project/sshtunnel/). Modifying the code from [Connecting to PostgreSQL database through SSH tunneling in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34965824/850848#37195241) for MongoDB connection URL, you get a code like this:

```
from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder

with SSHTunnelForwarder(
     ssh_hostname, ssh_username=ssh_username, ssh_pkey=ssh_key, # or ssh_password
     remote_bind_address=(mongo_host, mongo_port)) as tunnel:

    self.uri = 'mongodb://{user}:{password}@{local_host}:{port}'.
        format(user=mongo_user, password=mongo_password, local_host=local_host,
           port=tunnel.local_bind_port)
```

If the Mongo database runs on the SSH server itself, then it will typically listen on the loopback interface only. In that case `mongo_host` should be set to `localhost`.

---

*Same question about PostgreSQL: [Setup SSH tunnel with Paramiko to access PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64291009/850848)*.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me. I checked the paramiko example above but did not understand and found this. [I took the code from here](https://gist.github.com/JinhaiZ/3ad536870b9853dbff11ab4241380c0d) and modified just a little bit for my needs.

```
def data_call(collection_name, query={}):
    from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder
    import pymongo

    MONGO_HOST = 'HOST' 
    SERVER_USER   = 'server_user'
    PRIVATE_KEY ='pem.txt'

    MONGO_USER='user_mongo'
    MONGO_PASS ='pass_mongo'

    MONGO_DB = "db"

    # define ssh tunnel
    server = SSHTunnelForwarder(
        MONGO_HOST,
        ssh_username=SERVER_USER,
        ssh_pkey=PRIVATE_KEY,
        remote_bind_address=('127.0.0.1', 27017)
    )

    # start ssh tunnel
    server.start()

    connection = pymongo.MongoClient('127.0.0.1', server.local_bind_port)
    db = connection[MONGO_DB]

    data = db[collection_name].find(query)
    return data
```

Answer (score 0):

In your connection info:

```
sql_local = {
    'mongomdm': {
        'host':'xx.xxx.xxx.xx',
        'user':'aaa', 
        'pkey':'/Users/satu/dua/tiga/config/settings/googlecloud_dev_rsa'}}
```

You can `pip install ssh-pymongo`, and then:

```
from ssh_pymongo import MongoSession

session = MongoSession('xx.xxx.xxx.xx', 
    user='aaa',
    key='/Users/satu/dua/tiga/config/settings/googlecloud_dev_rsa',
    uri='mongodb://{mongo-user}:{mongo-password}@{host}:{local-port}'
)

db = session.connection['db-name']
```

More information on another post: [How to connect remote mongodb with pymongo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42718547/how-to-connect-remote-mongodb-with-pymongo/63598332#63598332) .

Answer (score 0):

just improving some other answer that actually helped me here

added the line  db.authenticate(MONGO_USER, MONGO_PASS)

rememberings :"MAKE AUTH ON MONGO!!!!"

and converted for a pandas dataframe if its useful for anyone (for me it was)

```
from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder
import pymongo
import pandas as pd


def data_call(collection_name, query={}):
    MONGO_HOST = 'ip.add.res'
    SERVER_USER = 'user'
    PRIVATE_KEY = 'PATH TO/id_rsa'

    MONGO_USER = 'mongouser'
    MONGO_PASS = 'mongopass'
    MONGO_DB = "dbname"
    # define ssh tunnel
    server = SSHTunnelForwarder(
        MONGO_HOST,
        ssh_username=SERVER_USER,
        ssh_pkey=PRIVATE_KEY,
        remote_bind_address=('127.0.0.1', dbport)
    )
    # start ssh tunnel
    server.start()

    
    connection = pymongo.MongoClient('localhost', server.local_bind_port)
    db = connection[MONGO_DB]
    db.authenticate(MONGO_USER, MONGO_PASS)


    data = pd.DataFrame(list(db[collection_name].find(query))).drop(columns=['_id'])

    return data
```