# Using paramiko ssh connections, specify local port for connection to remote MongoDB instance

Tags: mongodb, ssh, port, paramiko, ssh-tunnel

I'm trying to connect to a MongoDB instance, that runs on a vm on a remote server. I'm able to connect to the vm on the remote server using paramiko to set up two nested ssh connections. I can execute shell commands on the vm, but I am not sure how I can use this connection to access the MongoDB instance. As far as I can tell I just need to get the local port for an open tcpip connection, that I can then pass to the MongoClient, but I am not able to set this up.

Here is the Code that works for me, connecting to the vm and executing a shell command there:

```
        remote = paramiko.SSHClient()
        remote.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        remote.connect(remote_ip, username=remote_username, password=remote_password)
        remote_transport = remote.get_transport()
        dest_addr = (vm_ip, 22)
        local_addr = (remote_ip, 22)
        remote_channel = remote_transport.open_channel("direct-tcpip", dest_addr, local_addr)

        vm = paramiko.SSHClient()
        vm.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        vm.connect(vm_ip, username=remote_username, password=remote_password, sock=remote_channel)

        stdin, stdout, stderr = vm.exec_command("mongod --version")
        print(stdout.read())
        exit()
```

However, I don't want to execute shell commands, but connect to a MongoDB instance, which I would expect to do with the following code:

```
        connection = MongoClient('127.0.0.1', tbd_local_port)
        db = connection["my_db"]
        data = db.list_collection_names()
        print(data)
```

But what value should the to be determined tbd_local_port have? My understanding of ssh and paramiko tells me that I would first have to open another channel. Something like:

```
        vm_transport = vm.get_transport()
        dest_addr = ('0.0.0.0', 8000)
        local_addr = ('127.0.0.1', local_port)
        vm_channel = vm_transport.open_channel("direct-tcpip", dest_addr, local_addr)
```

And then I could connect the service on the local port. But I'm not able to open any such channel. I'm not sure if I'm just not using the right local and destination addresses. Or whats wrong. When I try to open this last channel, I just get a generic:

```
paramiko.ssh_exception.ChannelException: ChannelException(2, 'Connect failed')
```

Does anyone know how I can use this nested ssh connection, which in theory already works, to connect to the MongoDB instance? Thanks!

Comment: Your port forwarding code does not make sense to me. It seems to me that you do not use the forwarding at all. Moreover the forwarding is wrong. It seems that you can actually connect directly to `vm_ip`, without any forwarding at all.

Comment: Ok, I've missed the `sock=remote_channel`. The `local_addr` is still wrong, but with `sock=remote_channel` it is not used. But with real port-forwarding (needed for database connection), it matters. Anyway, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/58405646/850848#58406438