# Setup SSH tunnel with Paramiko to access PostgreSQL

Tags: python, postgresql, ssh, paramiko, ssh-tunnel

I currently use Paramiko to access an SFTP server and connect to the PostgreSQL on the same server. I found many examples using `sshtunnel` to log on PostgreSQL. But I don't know how to do it with pure Paramiko.

Currently my code looks something like:

```
# establish SSH tunnel
self.ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
self.ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
self.ssh.connect(hostname=host, username=user, password=password)

# setup SFTP server
self.sftp = self.ssh.open_sftp()

# connect to datebase
self.engine = create_engine('postgres+psycopg2://{}:{}@{}:{}/{}'.format(user, password, host, port, db))
```

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that [`sshtunnel`](https://pypi.org/project/sshtunnel/) is just a wrapper around Paramiko. So in general, you can use it to simplify the code, unless you have some restrictions preventing you from installing additional packages.

For example: [Connecting to PostgreSQL database through SSH tunneling in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34965824/850848)

If you cannot install it, you basically can reuse its code at least.

---

*Obligatory warning: Do not use `AutoAddPolicy` - You are losing a protection against [MITM attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) by doing so. For a correct solution, see [Paramiko "Unknown Server"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10670217/850848)*.