# Python: Connect to an Azure PostgreSQL instance through SSH Tunnel

Tags: python, postgresql, azure, ssh

I am trying to use Python to connect to a PostgreSQL instance, which is located on Azure through an SSH tunnel. I can connect to the database with DBeaver with no Problem.
Here is the code that I am using.

```
from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder

server = SSHTunnelForwarder(
    ('160.**.**.**', 22),
    ssh_username="*******",
    ssh_password="*******",
    remote_bind_address=('localhost', 5432))

server.start()
print("server connected")

params = {
    'database': '*******',
    'user': '*****postgresadmin@*****dev-postgres',
    'password': '************',
    'host': '**********-postgres.postgres.database.azure.com',
    'port': server.local_bind_port
}

conn = psycopg2.connect(**params)
cur = conn.cursor()

text = "select * from table"
cur.execute(text)
```

However I get the following error:

`conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync) psycopg2.OperationalError: could not translate host name "**********-postgres.postgres.database.azure.com" to address: Unknown host`

I also tried sqlalchemy using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34965824/connecting-to-postgresql-database-through-ssh-tunneling-in-python) with the same result.
Any idea on what I am doing wrong? Do I maybe need the IP-address of the host instead of the domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SSHTunnelForwarder is used if you want to do some stuff on the remote server.

Another code block is needed if you need to use remote server as a bridge to connect to another server:

```
import sshtunnel

with sshtunnel.open_tunnel(
    (REMOTE_SERVER_IP, 443),
    ssh_username="",
    ssh_password="*******",
    remote_bind_address=(AZURE_SERVER_HOST, 22),
    local_bind_address=('0.0.0.0', 10022)
) as tunnel:
    params = {
        'database': '*******',
        'user': '*****postgresadmin@*****dev-postgres',
        'password': '************',
        'host': '127.0.0.1',
        'port': 10022
    }

    conn = psycopg2.connect(**params)
    cur = conn.cursor()

    text = "select * from table"
    cur.execute(text)
```